# ignore certain buffers using iswitchb

Tags: emacs, iswitchb-mode

GNU Emacs 23.1

I am using iswitchb. However, when I press <kbd>C-x b</kbd> I get a list of buffers. However, I don't want to display one like scratch, Messages, GNU Emacs, etc. Just the buffers I have opened myself.

So I am looking for a way to ignore these buffers. This is what I have in my configuration. However, it doesn't ignore the buffers I don't want. Have I done anything wrong?

```
;; Setup iswitchb to select different buffers, ignore buffers to reduce list
(iswitchb-mode 1)
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore '("*scratch*"))
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore '("*Messages*"))
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore '("*GNU Emacs*"))
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore '("*compilation*"))
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`iswitch-buffer-ignore` should be set to a list of buffers to ignore, but you're setting a new list of one buffer at each step. I should change your code to something like this or pass all the buffers at once.

```
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "^ ")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Messages*")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*ECB")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Buffer")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Completions")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*ftp ")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*bsh")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*jde-log")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "^[tT][aA][gG][sS]$")
```

Alternatively:

```
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore '("*scratch*" "*Messages*" ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending to the list of ignored buffer, but rather overwriting it. You want the function `add-to-list`:

```
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "ignored buffer")
```

Repeat that for each item you want to ignore.